# How to fill a column of a dataframe (df1) with info from another dataframe (df2)? Just when two column info matches in df1 and df2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a df1 with 10k rows like:

```
name  time  day  details  year

xxx    1    mon   AA

yyy    2    tue   BB

zzz    3    mon   CC
```

And i have a df2 with 2k rows like:

```
  time   details  year
   4      AA       1900

   2      BB       2000

   5      CC       2030
```

When time and details of row  of df1 is equal to time and detals of the row in df2, i want
get the year info of df2 and update df1.
The desire df is like that:

```
name  time  day  details  year
    
xxx    1    mon   AA

yyy    2    tue   BB   2000

zzz    3    mon   CC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a 'left' [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) on 'time' and 'details':

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'],
    'time': [1, 2, 3],
    'day': ['mon', 'tue', 'mon'],
    'details': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
    'year': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [4, 2, 5],
    'details': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
    'year': [1900, 2000, 2030]
})

merged = df1.drop(columns='year').merge(df2, on=['time', 'details'], how='left')

print(merged)
```

`merged`:

```
  name  time  day details    year
0  xxx     1  mon      AA     NaN
1  yyy     2  tue      BB  2000.0
2  zzz     3  mon      CC     NaN
```